# Facings issues with Camera 0.2.0 and flutter 0.9.0

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to setup camera 0.2.0 with flutter 0.9.0 in order to make app cater non AndroidX mobiles but I am facing weird error. I was not getting this error in the latest stable version of flutter.

My main.dart code file is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './app/alert_on_crises.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:async';
List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  // SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
     //   DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    //   DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  // ]);
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(new AlertOnCrises(cameras));
}
```

And app logs when it starts

```
E/flutter (12582): 
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] 
Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (12582): NoSuchMethodError: Attempted to use type 
'CameraDescription' as a function. Since types do not define a method 
'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the 
CameraDescription constructor and forget the 'new' operator? 
E/flutter (12582): Receiver: CameraDescription
E/flutter (12582): Tried calling: CameraDescription(lensDirection: 
Instance of 'CameraLensDirection', name: "0")
E/flutter (12582): #0 Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core- 
patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
E/flutter (12582): #1 availableCameras. 
(package:camera/camera.dart:55)
E/flutter (12582): #2 MappedListIterable.elementAt 
(dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414)
E/flutter (12582): #3 ListIterable.toList 
(dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219)
E/flutter (12582): #4 availableCameras (package:camera/camera.dart:59)
E/flutter (12582): 
E/flutter (12582): #5 main 
(file:///home/nishant/alert_on_crises/lib/main.dart:13)
E/flutter (12582): 
E/flutter (12582): #6 _startIsolate. (dart:isolate- 
patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:279)
E/flutter (12582): #7 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage 
(dart:isolate- 
patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
Syncing files to device vivo 1723... 5.8s

fire To hot reload your app on the fly, press "r". To restart the app 
entirely, press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on vivo 1723 is available at: 
http://127.0.0.1:8101/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
```

Comment: Please include the code also, without it it's quite hard to say anything else than ask did you check if the suggestion in the error message is helpful? Or is it entirely from the package made by others?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have added the code of the main.dart file.